# Change scroll orientation forward and backwards on waypoint of a nested section

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a one page application that will have sections which are nested.

main wayward section with nest
https://jsfiddle.net/zfLp7d6m/3/

So when the user hits slide 2 -- I want the vertical scrolling to pause and for the next slide to scroll horizontal to slide 3 --- then 4 -- then resume vertical scroll.

If the user goes back up -- then the pause occurs when it its hit slide 4, then 3, then 2 - then resume vertical scroll

```
      var $nested = $('.nested');
      var $win = $(window);

      $nested.waypoint(function(direction) {
        console.log("direction", direction);

      if (direction == 'down') {
          console.log("pause and slide right");
          //scroll width -- pause vertical scroll and scroll right - end slide
        //$dipper.addClass("js-dipper-animate");
        } else {
          console.log("pause and slide left");
            //scroll width - pause vertical scroll and scroll left - start slide
        //$dipper.removeClass("js-dipper-animate");
        }
      }, {
        offset: '50%'
      });


$(window).scroll(function () {
    ///any use for this function?    
});
```

---

other example
https://jsfiddle.net/64Lzc1pg/1/

horizontal scroll
https://jsfiddle.net/5gf6envz/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

If you want to do it by yourself you need to capture the mouse wheel event, prevent the browser scrolling, and then use `scrollBy` and/or `scrollTop` to scroll the height of your slide (you can get the height this way: `Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)`). This way you will face a lot of corner cases and cross-platform problems so I recommend to use the other approach.

Comment: I am getting undefined issues with the scrollby -- I have seen the use of the transform tool -- but do I need to compact the nested sections?

Comment: I've tried to add a sticky to make the nested element a fixed element -- but then I tried to transform the children -- I am unsure if I need to flatten the elements - or turn it into an actual slider unit and then control the slider somehow with the scrolltop value?  https://jsfiddle.net/01u9ywr7/

Comment: I've made this -- which controls the swipe -- on scroll - but its very bespoke - is this how some of these sites are handling sections -- https://jsfiddle.net/01u9ywr7/1/

Comment: this is what I've come up with so far -- https://jsfiddle.net/zny0c8s6/